# Ajax - após chamada dele as minhas funções não estão funcionando

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Oi pessoal essa  é a minha primeira pergunta então vamos lá.
estou desenvolvendo uma página para android aonde conta com apenas js, html e jquery, eu fiz um back que busca informações no banco de dados a partir de um forma que envia esses dados para a página php, após isso ele carrega em uma table , porém ao carregar a página no inicio mesmo ele carrega um select a partir de um ajax tambem. esse código aqui

```
    function carregaform(){
          var url = "http://localhost/app2/www/phps/selecttr.php";
          $.getJSON(url,function(result){
          console.log(result);
          $.each(result, function(i, field){

                var id = field.id_tr;
                var nome = field.nome_tr;
                $('#select').append("<option value=" + id + " class='opt'>" + nome + "</option>");
              }

          );
        }
       );
      }
```

e após eu chamar a segunda parte do código que é a busca para inserir na table os resultador ele não funciona mais essa função de carregar o form(carregaform()) e nem outras funções que criei.
A função que eu criei para levar as informações.

```
function valida_form(){
                var src = formulario.src.value;
                var empre = formulario.select.value;

                        if(src.length == "" ){
                            formulario.src.focus();
                            return false;
                       }
                        else if(empre.length == ""){
                            formulario.src.focus();
                            return false;
                       }
                        else{

                            $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "http://localhost/app2/www/phps/conecta.php",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {src:src, select:empre},
                            success: function(retorno){

                                var hashes = retorno.split('&');
                                if(hashes.length > 2){
                                    for(var i = 0;i < hashes.length; i++){

                                    var titulo = decodeURI(getUrlTitulo(retorno)[i]);

                                    for(z=0;z < titulo.length;z++){
                                        titulo = titulo.replace("_"," ");
                                    }
                                        var conteudo = decodeURI(getUrlConteudo(retorno)[i]);
                                        var conteudo2 = conteudo.replace(/[\\"]/g,'');
                                        $("table").append("<tr id='t_titulo'>" + "<th>" + titulo + "</th>" + " </tr><td id = 't_conteudo'> " + conteudo2 + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                                    }

                                }
                                else{
                                    alert("Não ha nenhum produto cadastrado com este codigo");
                                    window.location.reload();
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                alert("Erro ao conectar com o arquivo, favor contatar o suporte");

                            }

                     });

                }
```

eu já tentei algumas coisas porem não foi como por exemplo:
No final do código

```
if(true){
                   carregaform();
                    ativa_botao_map();
                }
```

porem ele apenas chama o ativa_botao_map, mas não funciona nada dessa função todo o conteudo dentro desta função não vai tambem... se alguem puder me ajuda ficarei grato pois estou a muito tempo tentando e não consigo de nenhuma maneira, sou novo com js e etc.

Comment: Nesse trecho `<option value=" + id + " class='opt'>` deveria conter aspas simples para atribuir o id `<option value='" + id + "' class='opt'>`

Comment: Irei atualizar e averiguar se o erro perssiste. Obrigado

Comment: Aqui `" </tr><td id = 't_conteudo'> "` fica assim: `" </tr><td id='t_conteudo'> "`